# Get the Cart Item key when using add_to_cart method in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, product

So I'm developing an e-commerce with WooCommerce, I'm adding a product manualy via `add_to_cart` function. I get the return value of add_to_cart (the order_item_id) and store at a custom table with some other values.

The problem is that in the payment gateways I'm trying to add a logic, and need to get these informations back from the DB, I tried to get the WC()->cart->cart_contents, do a foreach and use the key to do a select in my custom table, but this key is a hash and the value returned by the add_to_cart function is an integer.

Someone can give me a help?

Answer (score 3):

WooCommerce `add_to_cart` will return a 'hash key' and not integer. Check like this.

```
global $woocommerce;

$addkey = $woocommerce->cart->add_to_cart('product ID', 'quantity');

foreach ( $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
    $cartkey = $cart_item['key'];
}
```

You can see both `$addkey` & `$cartkey` return the same value.

Answer (score 1):

> Normally if you look in the source code of the [`WC_Cart` `add_to_cart()`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Cart.html#1023-1128) method, on a successful add to cart, the right needed **cart item key** is returned, like:
>
> ```
> $cart_item_key = add_to_cart( $product_id );
> ```

Now you could use a custom function hooked in [`woocommerce_add_to_cart`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Cart.html#1118) to get the necessary **cart_item_key** and store all necessary related information in your custom database.

There is all the necessary arguments in this hooked function that you can use for it:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart', 'custom_action_add_to_cart', 20, 6 );
function custom_action_add_to_cart( $cart_item_key, $product_id, $quantity, $variation_id, $variation, $cart_item_data ){
    // HERE come your code
}
```

This hook is triggered each time `add_to_cart()` function is used.